# How to take a single picture with Kurento?

Tags: node.js, image, record, kurento

Is it possible to take a picture which is streamed to the kurento server instead of just recording videos?

Answer (score 1):

There is no open source media endpoint that exposes the functionality of capturing just one frame. You can

- Modify one of the endpoints to expose this functionality.
- Capture the frame in the client, from the video tag. Check [this](https://github.com/ilkkao/capture-video-frame) code, for instance.